# find all fucntion such $0<|f(x)-f(y)|<2|x-y|$

Tags: functions

Find  all function $f:N^{+}\to N^{+}$,and for any postive  integer $x\neq y$, such
$$0<|f(x)-f(y)|<2|x-y|$$

I think $f(x)=cx,c<2?$ it's right?

Comment: What about f(x)=x+1?

Comment: $f(x) = cx$ is not a function $N^+\to N^+$ when $c$ is not an interger, if by $N^+$ you mean the set of positive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0<|f(n+1)-f(n)|<2\implies |f(n+1)-f(n)|=1\;(\because f:\mathbb N^{+}\to\mathbb N^{+})\\|f(n+1)-f(n)|=1\implies \color{blue}{f(n+1)=f(n)\pm 1}$$

> $f(n+1)=f(n)+1\implies f(n+2)=f(n+1)+1$

Proof:
$$0<|f(n+2)-f(n)|<4\implies |f(n+2)-f(n)|=1,2,3\;(\because f:\mathbb N^{+}\to\mathbb N^{+})\\f(n+2)=\begin{cases}f(n)\pm1=f(n+1)-1\pm1&\color{blue}{\text{contradiction}}\\
f(n)\pm2=f(n+1)-1\pm2=\color{blue}{f(n+1)-1+2}\\
f(n)\pm3=f(n+1)-1\pm3&\color{blue}{\text{contradiction}}\end{cases}$$
So the only possible choice is $f(n+2)=f(n)+2=f(n+1)+1$

> $f(n+1)=f(n)-1\implies f(n+2)=f(n+1)-1$

Proof: Similar

> Conclusion:

$f(n)=f(1)+n-1$ or $f(n)=f(1)-(n-1)$. The latter doesn't work as $f:\mathbb N^{+}\to\mathbb N^{+}$ as pointed out by *almagest*.

Comment: Presumably $N^+$ means the positive integers, so $f(n)=f(0)-n$ does not work.